# Is there a general algorithm to identify a numeric series?

Tags: r, algorithm

I am looking for a general purpose algorithm to identify short numeric series from lists with a max length of a few hundred numbers. This will be used to identify series of masses from mass spectrometry (ms1) data.

For instance, given the following list, I would like to identify that 3 of these numbers fit the series N + 1, N +2, etc.

```
426.24  <= N
427.24  <= N + 1/x
371.10
428.24  <= N + 2/x
851.47
451.16
```

The series are all of the format: N, N+1/x, N+2/x, N+3/x, N+4/x, etc, where x is an integer (in the example x=1). I think this constraint makes the problem very tractable. Any suggestions for a quick/efficient way to tackle this in R?

Comment: I don't think this is a R question. If you have an algorithm and want to know how to efficiently implement in R then it would make sense. Anyway Do you know N? You can subtract N from all values. Also it's not clear what is the requirement?

Comment: N can be empirically determined as the first number of the series.  Subtracting N from all values and then looking for duplicated values is a pretty good solution actually.

Comment: In this example, if you looked at `diff(sort(x))` it would be quite obvious. But that wouldn't work so well if other values overlapped with the series values.

Answer (score 2):

This routine will generate series using x from 1 to 10 (you could increase it). And will check how many are contained in the original list of numbers.

```
N = c(426.24,427.24,371.1,428.24,851.24,451.16)
N0 = N[1]
x = list(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
L = 20

Series = lapply(x, function(x){seq(from = N0, by = 1/x,length.out = L)})
countCoincidences = lapply(Series, function(x){sum(x %in% N)})
```

Result:

```
unlist(countCoincidences)
[1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2
```

As you can see, using x = 1 will have 3 coincidences. The same goes for all x until x=9.  Here you have to decide which x is the one you want.

Comment: I ended up going with this approach because it was more straightforward and I could check for +/- experimental error easily.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're looking for an arithmetic sequence, the difference *k* is constant. Thus, you can loop over the vector and subtract each value from the sequence. If you have a sequence, subtracting the second term from the vector will result in values of *-k*, 0, and *k*, so you can find the sequence by looking for matches between vector - value and its opposite, value - vector:

```
x <- c(426.24, 427.24, 371.1, 428.24, 851.47, 451.16)

unique(lapply(x, function(y){
    s <- (x - y) %in% (y - x); 
    if(sum(s) > 1){x[s]}
}))

# [[1]]
# NULL
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 426.24 427.24 428.24
```

Comment: This approach is really nice. However, I have to do some adjustments to account for experimental error (to ~10ppm). This radically simplified approach doesn't really let me deal with that. I need to think about how to modify it.

Comment: The simplest way is probably to use `round`, e.g. `s <- round(x - y, 1) %in% round(y - x, 1)`, if that's precise enough.